# MySQL Server not binding to external addresses

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and MySQL server 5.5. I have commented out skip-networking and bind-address in my.cnf. However, when I try to access the MySQL externally, I get error 111 and I am unable to connect to the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may need to check your user privileges, as they can also raise error 111, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111) (3rd answer).

Answer (score 1):

My user permissions only allowed my user to connect from a local ip address. I changed it to allow it to login from all IP addresses and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup port forwarding on your router? I had a similar issue a couple of months ago and found that my forwarding was not setup correctly